# If there is a cable and jack standard for I2C?

Tags: i2c, standard

I want to do a connection of multiple current and voltage meters, they connect by I2C. Is for to monitor solar panels and batteries, they will be a considerable distance from the master. I thinking use a 6P6C or RJ45 connectors for this. But first I want to know if there is a standard for cable colors or another type of connector for this, just for follow the protocols in case I want to expand my system or buy a new device.

Comment: I doubt it. I2C wasn't originally designed to be used with such connectors.

Comment: For long distance, use one of these: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14589

Comment: use lan cables ... that way you are not forced to make your own

Comment: DrakoPD - If you are concerned about (or didn't know about) the issues when using I2C over a long distance (which you mention you are doing "in passing" in the question), use the search box above and try the search term - I2C long distance - to see previous Q&A on the topic.

Comment: You can use a TRS (3 wire) 3.5mm jack and cable for SCL, SDA and GND but, yes, I2C wasn't designed for this, and the signal might degrade over the length of the cable, especially at higher frequencies.

Comment: @SamGibson I'm aware of i2c over long distances, what I was not aware of was high frequency over long distances. As QuickishFM said. Thanks both for your answer, now I'm evaluating my system and research for solve possible issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I2C specification does not specify any connector, as it is not a specification for an external interface. Many technologies that are based on I2C do specify a connector and pinout for an external interface, for example Access.bus has 4-pin connector. Lego Mindstorms also implements I2C over 6P6C connectors.

Answer (score 5):

See [Access.bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACCESS.bus), a form of I2C designed for low-speed desktop devices with hot-plug capability. Unfortunately, it was quickly overshadowed by USB, which came out shortly afterward.